# Problem installing wireless adapter driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, 15.10, adapter

Up until now I've been using a wired connection on my PC (running Ubuntu 15.10) but a recent move has required that I try to connect with a wireless USB adapter (ASUS dual band AC56R).  I've gotten to the point where I've been able to see the contents of my companion Cd where there is clearly a folder designated for Linux, but I have no idea how to install the necessary files. Help?

Comment: Please list the contents of the `linux` folder, may be there is an installer.

Comment: There's an install shell script but I don't know what I'm looking for

Comment: Please list the contents of the linux folder, I cant find it on there site and it could be called anything!

Comment: when I open the Linux folder, there's a folder called: RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS.zip and after this is opened I get a series of folders titled android_ref_codes_JB_4.1 etc and folders that say "document", "driver", "hardware_wps_pbc", "WiFi_Direct_User_Interface", "Wireless_tools" and "wpa_supplicant_hostapad" followed by install.sh, readme.txt and ReleaseNotes.pdf

Comment: What is in that? Ignore the folders find me one with files in.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I've looked through most of the folders, looking for a way to install whatever it is that I need installed.  the best path that I came across so far was wireless_tools >> wireless_tools.30.rtl.tar.gaz >> wireless_tools.30.rtl >> install but that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First copy the folder `RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS.zip` from your CD to your `/home` folder and open a terminal, extract it with

```
unzip ~/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS.zip
```

This will make a folder called `RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS` change to this folder

```
cd ~/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS
```

The file to run is `install.sh`, use this command to give it executable permissions

```
chmod +X install.sh
```

Install it with this command

```
sudo sh install.sh
```

This will install your driver

Please [see this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting) for more information on .sh files.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As you are a new user if this helps you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to easily find this information

Comment: this did something.  now how do I get it to connect to my router?  sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Reboot your PC and just use the network manager icon (wifi) in the top right of the taskbar

Comment: I have an icon up there, but it doesn't give me the option to connect wirelessly.  do I need to create that myself, or is it searchable?

Comment: There are no options?

Comment: when I click on the network connections icon, I have a small box that says "Ethernet" >> Wired connection 1 and on the side, I have the options to add, edit and delete (and close, but that doesn't count).  There are no other options telling me that i can connect to my router.

Comment: OK are you sure the driver actually installed, what was the terminal output?

Comment: terminal output was good with the exception 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
target '/home/nickandcam/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS/core/rtw_debug.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/nickandcam/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS/core/rtw_debug.o]

Comment: Error 1
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/home/nickandcam/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/nickandcam/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-22-generic'
Makefile:1295: recipe for target 'modules' failed

Comment: That means it failed to build, run this command, reboot and the try to run install.sh again `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential`